# Draw ERD for a project using SQL + NoSQL databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, mongodb, nosql, erd

For my graduation project, I need to draw a ERD to combine 2 databases,
SQL for authentication and NoSQL for other data like articles and posts and tasks.

How can I specifically display relationships between user (SQL) and their posts (NoSQL) or articles (NoSQL) in the ERD for example the 1:m relationship.

Is that possible or can't I make a relationship between SQL and NoSQL?

Comment: basicaly you have a table that is not dbo.mastertable it is mongodb.entitity. it is rare because most use the abilities of their database for nosql rudemenetary as it can be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An ERD is more abstract than a database schema, and so has no information about whether the data model is instantiated in an RDBMS or a JSON document database, or some hybrid of the two.

After you have completed the ERD then select some entities to store in an RDBMS and produce a relational data model for those, and some entities to store in a document database, and produce a JSON schema for those.

NB when modeling for a document database great care must be taken to group entities into documents.  Typically each document will have one main entity an zero-or-more related weak entities.  And entities may be repeated across multiple documents in whole or in part.